# Reverse alphabetic sort multidimensional PHP array maintain key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm dying here, any help would be great.

I've got an array that I can sort  a-z on the value of a specific key but cannot sort in reverse z-a.

sample of my array which i'd like to sort by ProjectName (z-a):

```
Array
( 
 [0] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [ProjectName] => bbcjob
        [Postcode] => 53.471922,-2.2996078
        [Sector] => Public

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [ProjectName] => commercial enterprise zone
        [Postcode] => 53.3742081,-1.4926439
        [Sector] => Public

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
        [ProjectName] => Monkeys eat chips
        [Postcode] => 51.5141492,-0.2271227
        [Sector] => Private
```

the desired results would be to maintain the entire array key -> value structure but with the order:

> Monkeys eat chips
>   Commericial enterprise zone
>   bbcjob

I hope this makes sense

Comment: So show us the code you use to sort A-Z, and we'll show you how to change it so it will sort Z-A

Comment: I used function name_sort($x, $y)
{
 return strcasecmp($x['ProjectName'], $y['ProjectName']);
}  and ran this through uasort with the array

Comment: Just reverse the sign of the returned value: `_sort($x, $y) { return -(strcasecmp($x['ProjectName'], $y['ProjectName'])); }` or reverse the order of the arguments: `_sort($y, $x) { return strcasecmp($x['ProjectName'], $y['ProjectName']); }`

Comment: Cheers Mark, can't believe i didn't think of that.  Defo a case of staring at a problem too long. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which lets you define a function to do your comparison and then sort the array based on that.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b["ProjectName"], $a["ProjectName"]);
}

usort($yourArray, "cmp");

print_r($yourArray);
```

Edit: based on your comment, you should just reverse the `$x` and `$y` in your function to reverse the order of the sorting performed.

```
function name_sort($x, $y) 
{
    return strcasecmp($y['ProjectName'], $x['ProjectName']); 
}
```